# rails custom validation after editing a field's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

basically I have a user model that has an amount and money field.  When I first create the user, I validate that `user.amount <= user.money`. However, the user is allowed to change the amount via 'edit'. In the update action, when the user changes the amount, I calculate the difference between the old and new (old minus new) amounts via

```
  amount_change = user.amount - params[:user][:amount].to_f
```

I don't know if this is good form but it works for me. Basically I'm not storing the difference and calculating it only as the user is trying to change the amount.  Anyway when the user edits, I would like to validate that `amount_change <= user.money` instead.  How can I do this? I feel like I should be passing something to the validation, but I don't know how I can pass in `amount_change` since it's calculated in the middle of the update method of my users controller.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) to access the old value (as `amount_was`):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validate :ensure_amount_change_less_than_money, 
           :on => :update, 
           :if => :amount_changed?

  def ensure_amount_change_less_than_money
    if (self.amount - self.amount_was) <= self.money
      errors.add(:money, 'Amount change must be less than money')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this seems to sort of work--there's an error on the first attempt if it does not pass validation, but if the user just clicks submit again, there is no error...is this because a new amount_was and amount was set? thanks! (also is _changed built in?)

Comment: You can try removing `:on => :update` and see if that works better for you. `_changed` is built into ActiveModel and ActiveRecord.

Comment: hmm I can't get the _changed to work for some reason :/ I get a NoMethodError. Does it matter that my real amount variable is called `start_amount`? I did `start_amount_changed?`. Thanks!

Comment: That's strange. First, check to see if `start_amount` is in `User.column_names` (maybe there is an alias or something). Also check `@user.changes` and see if that gives a `NoMethodError` .